New install of Ubuntu 24.04 server with RAID1 (md) - Not finding a way to do it from USB
Greeting to all,
I have done this type of install once before for Ubuntu 16.04 server. But I cannot see a way to accomplish the install of (md) RAID1 on two partitions. I am attempting to install on two partitions on separate NVME devices. Including a swap partition on a third NVME device (for hibernate). This will be a single boot system.
I am not using any encryption or other sophisticated options. I just cannot find how to perform a RAID1 install as I have done in the past. The system I am installing on has 4 NVME devices each one a 4 TB module in the system. The partitions I want to install on will be 1 TB primary partitions on a gpt label.
The documentation I have found indicate to:

Select the first drive you want as boot-partition and select as boot partition.
Select the second drive and select as another boot partition.

I have not found any way to do this using the USB media I created from the 24.04 server download. The image I downloaded is: ubuntu-24.04-live-server-amd64.iso. I also created a USB live install of the desktop install and did not find it there. But that is what I expected.
So I need to discover what I am doing incorrectly, or what I am missing when installing from USB media build with the current download of 24.04 server.
I appreciate any and all suggestions, recommendations, pointers or directions. Thanks in advance.
